How to display custom pages based on email validation with Clerk authentication in a Next.js application?
I'm working on a Next.js application using Clerk for user authentication. I need to implement a feature where users are redirected to different pages based on whether their Google account email is registered in our database. If the email exists, they should be redirected to a custom "Select Account" page. If the email does not exist, they should be redirected to an "Account Not Registered" page.
Here is the code snippet where I'm handling the sign-in:
import { useClerk, useSignIn } from "@clerk/nextjs";

const { isLoaded, signIn } = useSignIn();

async function handleSignIn(strategy) {
  await signIn.authenticateWithRedirect({
    strategy,
    redirectUrl: "/login",
    redirectUrlComplete: "/login",
  });
}

I am unsure where to place the logic to check if the user's email exists in our database and how to redirect them accordingly. Should this logic be placed in the redirectUrlComplete callback, or is there a better approach to handle this within the Clerk framework?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Well first of all, i want to know which authentication method are you using, is it credentials, or is it magic links (email provider)

@HairyHandKerchief23 Its google

When you say our database do you mean your own custom database or Clerk's database.

This question is similar to: Next.js with Clerk Auth - how to detect if a user just signed up?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
